# Returning a object after adapter item click

Tags: android

I'm getting an error when trying to return an object.
The error comes from an onClick function, which goes to the ProductActivity.
I'm trying to pass the Product ID data via arguments, am I doing it wrong or why am I getting this error?
The error is :

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.example.cmd.testproject/com.example.cmd.testproject.Fragments.ProductFragment};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
            public class ProductListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnClickListener {
                private TextView mTitle,mDesc,mPrice;
                private ImageView imageView;

                private Product mProduct;

                public void bind(Product product) {
                    this.mProduct = product;
                    mTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
                    mDesc.setText(product.getDesc());
                    mPrice.setText(product.getPrice());
                    //TODO: Set Image
                }

                public ProductListHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
                    super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false));
                    mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    mDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
                    mPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        //            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgUrl);

                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = ProductActivity.newIntent(ctx,mProduct.getId());
                    ctx.startActivity(i);
                }
            }

        }

public class ProductActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    public static final String PRODUCT_ID = "com.example.cmd.testproject.Activitys.productId";

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        UUID id = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(PRODUCT_ID);
        return ProductFragment.newInstance(id);
    }

    public static Intent newIntent(Context ctx, UUID prodID) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ProductFragment.class);
        i.putExtra(PRODUCT_ID,prodID);
        return i;
    }
}

public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARGUMENT_PROD_ID = "prod_id";

    private TextView mTitle,mDesc,mImgUrl,mPrice;
    private List<Product> mProducts;
    private Product product;



               @Override
                protected Fragment createFragment() {
                    UUID id = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(PRODUCT_ID);
                    return ProductFragment.newInstance(id);
                }

                public static Intent newIntent(Context ctx, UUID prodID) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ProductFragment.class);
                    i.putExtra(PRODUCT_ID,prodID);
                    return i;
                }
            }


           public static Fragment newInstance(UUID productID) {
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putSerializable(ARGUMENT_PROD_ID,productID);
                ProductFragment frag = new ProductFragment();
                frag.setArguments(args);
                return frag;
            }

            public ProductFragment() {}

            @Override
            public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                UUID id = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARGUMENT_PROD_ID);
                product = ProductHolder.get(getActivity()).getProduct(id);

            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_fragment,container,false);
                setWidgets(v);
                return v;
            }

            private void setDataOnText(){
                mTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
                mDesc.setText(product.getDesc());
                mPrice.setText(product.getPrice());
            }

            private void setWidgets(View v) {
                mTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                mDesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                mPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
            }
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cmd.testproject">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activitys.ProductActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activitys.ProductListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Have you passed the context from fragment into adapter..?

Answer (score 1):

ProductFragment is a fragment not activity.You cannot use intent to load a fragment.Change newIntent method to load fragment.

```
 public static void newIntent(Context ctx, UUID prodID) {
        ProductFragment fragmentA=new ProductFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(your_container_id, fragmentA, fragmentA.getClass().getName());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: I solved the problem, i was starting a Fragment instead of Activity, and i have the fragmentTransaction code in a seperate abstract class that my activitys implement